# Confusing debugging error in Fortran program

Tags: debugging, gdb, fortran, memory-address

I've been sitting here for a while quite baffled as to why my debugger keeps displaying an error in my code when the program runs fine. There are three parts to a very simple program that is just reading in information from a file.

My code is broken into three Fortran files given below and compiled via

> ifort -o test global.f90 read.f90 test.f90

global.f90:

```
module global
  implicit none
  integer(4), parameter :: jsz = 904
end module global
```

read.f90:

```
subroutine read(kp,q,wt,swt)
implicit none
integer(4) :: i, j
integer(4), intent(in) :: kp
real(8), intent(out) :: swt, q(kp,3), wt(kp)
swt = 0.0d0; q(:,:) = 0.0d0; wt(:) = 0.0d0
open(7,file='test.dat')
read(7,*) ! Skipping a line
do i = 1, kp
  read(7,1000)(q(i,j),j=1,3), wt(i)
  swt = swt + wt(i)
end do
close(7)
return
1000 format(3F10.6,1X,1F10.6)
end subroutine read
```

test.f90:

```
program test
use global
integer(4) :: i, j
real(8) :: tot, qq(jsz,3), wts(jsz)
call read(jsz,qq,wts,tot)
stop
end program test
```

The error I keep receiving is

```
Breakpoint 1, read (kp=904, 
q=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x69bb80>,
wt=..., swt=6.9531436082559572e-310) at read.f90:6
```

This error appears right when the subroutine of `read` is called. In other words, I'm adding a breakpoint at the `read` subroutine and running the code in gdb after the breakpoint is added. The program will continue to run as expected and give the correct outputs when I include write statements in the 'test' program. However, if I use the gdb print options I receive an error of 'Cannot access memory at address 0x69bb80' for array `q` only. All other arrays and variables can be displayed with no problems.

As I would like the `read` subroutine to be a stand alone subroutine and not necessarily use any global parameters, I have not used the global module and instead called the variable `kp` into the subroutine. I decided to test whether using the global module would help, and if I use `jsz` in place of `kp`, I do indeed remove the error. However, since this isn't my overall goal with the subroutine, I would hopefully like to figure out how to fix this without the use of the global module. (I also tried not using the global at all and setting the parameter variable of `kp` in the `test.f90` program directly, but this also gives the error.)

Any insight on possible reasons for this error, or suggestions to try and fix the memory addressing issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What compiler are you using, I just compiled the code without a problem on the INTEL compiler in a Mac OSX? I have frequently had problems recompiling code originally developed on the INTEL compiler with the gfortran compiler, if that is what you are using.

Comment: From the question it is evident he uses `ifort`.

Comment: As Vladimir has mentioned, I am in fact using the intel compiler. I believe it's version 13 on Fedora 19, with gdb version 7.6.1-42.

Comment: To add to my last comment, I just compiled on two different computers, both with ifort 13.0.0 20120731 and fedora 19. However, the debuggers are slightly different 7.6.1-42 for one and 7.6.1-46 for the other. Same error if I keep the files separate or make it one single file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue specific to the ifort+gdb combination that is fixed with newer gdb versions. Here's a smaller example to reproduce the issue:

```
$ cat test.f90 
  subroutine bar(arg)
    integer, intent(inout):: arg

    print *, 'bar argument is', arg
    arg = 42
  end subroutine bar

  program test
    integer:: param
    param = 3
    call bar(param)
    print *, 'post-bar param:', param
  end program test
$ ifort -g -O0 -o test test.f90
$ gdb --quiet test
Reading symbols from /home/nrath/tmp/test...done.
(gdb) b 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402bd0: file test.f90, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/nrath/tmp/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, bar (arg=@0x2aaa00000003) at test.f90:4
4       print *, 'bar argument is', arg
(gdb) p arg
$1 = (REF TO -> ( INTEGER(4) )) @0x2aaa00000003: <error reading variable>
(gdb) quit
$ gdb --version | head -1
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
```

However, if you compile with gfortran instead of ifort, or if you use GDB 7.7.1, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `INTERFACE` statement to the end of your programme?
You need it when you call a function that is not contained in the programme.

Comment: This is not true. The explicit interface (not the `inteface` block) is sometimes necessary, but not in this case. A module is almost always better alternative to an `interface` block.

Comment: The function the user is trying to call is, however, not part of the module but a subroutine in a separate file. If a subroutine is external, so not part of module or main programme, the `interface` is required.

Comment: It is not. There are conditions for this in the standard.

Comment: I'll check out the interface option, but I have never had this problem before and I have never used interface in the past. Nearly all my code is written as individual files and compiled either by a single line like I gave above, or via makefile.

Comment: You don't have to do an interface block, just move the subroutine to the module for a better effect. It will probably cure nothing. I tried that, but I don't get your original error in the first place. BTW, it is OK to have everything in one big file, at least for testing. You can also use `ifort` option `-warn interfaces` to see if interfaces are a probable problem.

Comment: Thank Vladimir. I'll try combining everything into one file and see if I continue to get the error. Ideally this is not what I'd prefer. The program I'm trying to create is going to be much more robust in the near future and the subroutines will be a lot larger. So for simplicity and all that, I'd rather have individual files. Anyway, I'll check out what you mentioned and let you know if that changes anything.